# Hardlink won't be created in docker container even if they are in same filesystem from host

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems

I try to run a docker container with mounting two different directory which are same filesystem.

```
    --> docker run -dt -v /tmp/a:/tmp/a -v /tmp/b:/tmp/b ubuntu 
ee1fc92beb750773218ca8ff5d9df8b42ad34b8a8a0b4e4cb532d2e6b92522d6
```

Since /tmp/a and /tmp/b are same filesystem in the host, it is possible to create hardlink between those folders.

```
kenta(:|✔) 17:38:55 %
[/tmp] 
--> cd /tmp/a 
kenta(:|✔) 17:38:59 %
[/tmp/a] 
--> ls
kenta(:|✔) 17:39:00 %
[/tmp/a] 
--> touch a 
kenta(:|✔) 17:39:04 %
[/tmp/a] 
--> ln a ../b 
kenta(:|✔) 17:39:10 %
[/tmp/a] 
--> ls
a
```

However I cannot create hardlink between those two directories from container .

```
    --> docker exec -it ee1fc92 /bin/bash 
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/# cd /tmp/
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp# cd a/  
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp/a# touch b
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp/b# cd ../
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp# ls
    a  b
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp# cd a/
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp/a# ls
    a  b
    root@ee1fc92beb75:/tmp/a# ln  b ../b/
    ln: failed to create hard link '../b/b' => 'b': Invalid cross-device link

I
```

want to resolve the issue without using copy command. Can we do this?

Comment: ...and you are surprised that this doesn't work, because...?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the container those directories are mount points, hence the correct error message.